# siunitx option retain-zero-exponent not working in tabular

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'm trying to format a table using `siunitx`. There's a column I want to have with scientific notation in which zero-exponents are retained, but the output doesn't put the zero-exponent there even with the `retain-zero-exponent` option set. I've tried debugging by doing silly things like changing the retain-zero-exponent option setting to being in the preamble and changing the input exponent symbol from `E` to `e` but nothing is working.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c
                S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, scientific-notation=true, retain-zero-exponent=true]}
{Thing}&     {Number}  \\
   Ex1&     7.91472E0  \\
   Ex2&     7.68513E-6 \\
   Ex3&     3.71188E0  \\
   Ex4&     9.30066E3  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably something that could be documented better: what you are seeing is an interaction between `scientific-notation` and `retain-zero-exponent`. When you set `scientific-notation = true` the code is auto-processing all numbers to be in normalised exponent form. That means that you no longer have the situation that the input exponents are retained. Thus `retain-zero-exponent` has (deliberately) no effect here.

Comment: I removed the `scientific-notation=true` from the option flags, and it now works well. It's a slightly annoying fix because in my actual data not all numbers are actually in scientific notation (e.g. a number might be 135.43), and so now I need to go in and convert those manually. Good enough for my particular case though.